# probability problem solution with full proof

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

n+4 apples are distributed at random among n persons. Find the probability that atleast one of them will receive none.

I want a detailed solve using complex combinatorial summation. Please help me to guide through with proofs

Comment: You may consider the complementary event, in which all of them receive at least one. Then for the remaining 4, you just use the usual stars and bars method to distribute as you have no restrictions for these 4.

Comment: @BGM please write in an answer form

Comment: ...And with some space left on top, so that you can add your name before giving it to your TA?

Comment: @Did I don't get you what you are trying to say friend

Comment: Are you sure? My guess is that you got the point perfectly.

Comment: @Did yes but the people who thinks themselves to be intelligent for instance Rohan closed this question as off topic. Totally nuisance

Comment: @ChenGuo Please get minimally informed about the rules of the site before spouting nonsense such as your last comment above. If you do, your analysis about **who is a "total nuisance" here**, might be slightly modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to distribute $n+4$ apples among $n$ people so that at least one person gets no apples is the number of ways to distribute the apples, minus the number of ways to distribute the apples so that each person gets at least one apple.  I take the question to mean that we only care about how many apples each person gets, not which apples he gets, so we have the problem of distributing $n+4$ indistinguishable objects among $n$ persons which is $$\binom{n+4 + n-1}{n-1} = \binom{2n+3}{n-1}$$.  This is the "balls and walls" or "stars and bars" formula.

To figure out how many ways to distribute the apples so that everyone gets at least one apple, just give everyone an apple, then distribute the remaining 4.  This is again a "balls and walls" problem, and the answer is $$\binom{4+n-1}{n-1} = \binom{n+3}{n-1},$$ so the final answer is $$\binom{2n+3}{n-1}-\binom{n+3}{n-1}.$$

Comment: wonderful answer. Thank you so much

Comment: It would be helpful if you remove the term " Rohan's answer" in your answer as it is already deleted. I request you to edit